# Floating when adding Time.deltaTime to movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

My movement is working fine without Time.deltaTime but when I add it to my player movement I can move left to right fine but I fall slowly and I cant jump

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Bson;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float horSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float vertSpeed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Boolean isJumping;
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // we store the initial velocity, which is a struct.
        var v = rb.velocity * Time.deltaTime;

        


        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && !isJumping)
        {
            vf.y = vertSpeed;
            isJumping = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            vf.x = -horSpeed;
        }
           

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            vf.x = horSpeed;
        }
           

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            vf.y = -vertSpeed;
        }
            

        rb.velocity = vf;

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }

}
```

I've added it to my enemy script and it works fine so im not sure whats different with player movement to using transform.position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you multiply the [`velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) by [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)?

This is used to convert a value from a "certain unit per frame" into a value "certain unit per second".

A velocity already **IS** a value in units per second.

> Linear velocity of the Rigidbody in **units per second.**

=> It makes no sense to apply `Time.deltaTime` here at all.

---

For your X axis movement it doesn't make much difference since you anyway apply that velocity continuously every frame. Here you just would probably want to handle the case where neither left nor right is pressed and set `vf.x = 0`.

For the Y axis however you apply the jump only once, just to divide it by about 60 (or whatever your frame rate is) right in the next frame => you never give it the chance to fall or jump.

---

In general you should modify the Rigidbody in `FixedUpdate`. In your specific case it is fine to do this in `Update`, it is just redundant work ;)

Comment: So in this case Time.deltaTime doesnt change anything?

Comment: Well, except the part where you noted yourself that it breaks things ;) Since you anyway apply X axis continuously it makes no difference .. but in Y axis you apply it only once and in the next frame already divide it by about 60 due to Time.deltaTime ... You probably would want to add a case for setting `vf.x = 0` if neither left nor right is pressed though